# ggplot2 forcing Date TIME (formating HH:MM) on X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do  I force the X axis label to date & hour (ex: 2019-10-05 07:00AM)

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

ggplot(data=reqsSum, aes(x=datetime, y=count))+
  geom_point()+ 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "hour")+  
  xlab("date")+ 
  ylab("count")
```

Comment: look at `date_labels` argument to `scale_x_datetime`

Comment: anyone can help with syntax ?

Comment: See the alphabet soup at `?strftime`. `"%Y/%m/%d %H"` will give you date and hour